# Form will not submit and gives error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, if-statement, jquery-events

I have a form that contains clothing sizes. When a user selects a size, they are able to submit the form.

My issue is that the user is able to submit the form whether or not they have selected a size. The code is much more complicated but below is a break down of the form, with the add to bag button below.

```
<form>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li class="size-value"></li>
        <li class="size-value"></li>
        <li class="size-value"></li>
        <li class="size-value"></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
<div class="mt10">
  <input type="submit" class="modalAddToBagButton">
</div>
```

When a user selects a size, the class `selected` is added, so it would read `class="size-value selected"`. This function is working fine. In my `.js` file I would like to add an `if/else` statement, where if an `<li class="size-value">` has been given the class `selected` (the user has clicked this size), then the form will be submitted, however if NO `<li>` has the class `selected`, the form will throw an error message. Below is the section of my function that I believe I should add the `if/else` statement:

```
}).on('click', '.modalAddToBagButton', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Add if/else statement here. if list items have a class selected, form can be submitted. if no list items have class selected, then display this error message.
  $(this).closest("#dialog-addToBag").find('form').submit();
});
```

My question is: How do I write this `if/else` statement? I am not sure how to access the form and list items from my input button, since they are outside the div and are quite nested, and to listen for if any of the list items have been given the class `selected` so that the form can be submitted, and if not to throw an error message. Can anyone help with this?

---

UPDATE:

This function works in not submitting the form and displaying the error message when no size is selected, however even when a size is selected the error message still appears and the form will not submit. Can anyone figure out why?

```
.on('click', '.modalAddToBagButton', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("es-value");
  var i = x.length;
  var selected = false;
  while (i--) {
    if (x[i].hasAttribute("selected")) {
      selected = true;
    }
  }
  if (selected == false) {
    //Displays error
    $("#errormessage").show();
  } else {

    $(this).closest("#dialog-addToBag").find('form').submit();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.on('click', '.modalAddToBagButton', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $form = $(this).closest("#dialog-addToBag").find('form');
    if( $( ".size-value.selected" ).length ) { //ho
        $form.submit();
    } else {
        $("#errormessage").show();
    }
});
```

Try this one

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
<div id="errorDiv"></div>
```

And inside your javascript function

```
}).on('click', '.modalAddToBagButton', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 

       var x = document.getElementsByClassName("size-value");
       var i = x.length;

       var selected = false;

       while(i--)
       {
           if (x[i].hasAttribute("selected"))
           {
              selected = true;        
           } 
       }

       if(selected == false)
       {
           //Displays error
           document.getElementById("errorDiv").innerHTML = "Please select a size.";

       } else {

          //Submit form
          $(this).closest("#dialog-addToBag").find('form').submit();
       }
});
```

Comment: i'm getting the error ".hasAttribute is not a function"

Comment: i'm a little confused, wouldn't the form be submitted if it has an attribute "selected" and the error would be thrown after the else part of the statement?

Comment: Just made an edit to submit when any class has the attribute 'selected'

Comment: this almost works, but now the error message appears even when a size is selected and i can't submit the form.

Comment: not getting those issues mentioned. got a modded example here https://codepen.io/modeexe/pen/wxWbXG

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would modify your HTML:

```
<form id="clothes-sizes">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li class="size-value"></li>
                <li class="size-value"></li>
                <li class="size-value"></li>
                <li class="size-value"></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="mt10">
        <input type="button" class="modalAddToBagButton">
    </div>

</form>
```

And this is my jQuery that you can adapt, above I gave your form an id and using it in my jQuery below to locate it. I've also change the button `type="button"` and have moved it inside the `<form>...</form>` tag...

```
var form = $("#clothes-sizes");
var btn = form.find(".modalAddToBagButton");

btn
.unbind("click")
.bind("click", function ()
{
    var selectedSizes = form.find("ul li.selected");

    if (!selectedSizes.length)
    {
        alert("Please select a size.");

        return false;
    }

    form.submit();
});
```

Comment: The trouble is I'm not able to move the button inside the form

Comment: It's fine you can move your button out of the form tag but by using the form#id you can find the form from anywhere in your script provided the form#id is unique...

Comment: Because I'm working within someone else's larger code I can't change the jQuery too much, but i placed if/else statement within my code and the form is still submitting even when no size is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a little bit :

```js
$('.modalAddToBagButton').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("size-value");
            var i = x.length;
            var selected = false;
            while(i--) {
                if (x[i].hasAttribute("selected")) {
                    selected = true;
                }
            }
            console.log('selected: ',x[0].innerText);
            if(selected == false) {
                $("#errormessage").show();
            } else {
              $( "#dialog-addToBag").submit();
            }           
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
   <ul>
     <li>
      <ul>
       <li class="size-value">1</li>
       <li class="size-value" selected>2</li>
       <li class="size-value">3</li>
       <li class="size-value">4</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
<div class="mt10">
   <input type="submit" class="modalAddToBagButton">
</div>
```

See if this helps.